# Setting port for gRPC server

Tags: http, tcp, grpc, http2

From my understanding, gRPC's protocol is http2 on top of TCP. Therefore, the maximum port that can be assigned is 65535, right? But it seems like if I set the server address to be something like "0.0.0.0:70040" which is out of the range, it is still working fine and the gRPC client is able to connect and communicate with the gRPC server. May I know what does this actually mean? Thank you.

```
builder.AddListeningPort("0.0.0.0:70040", grpc::InsecureServerCredentials());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that, the use of strings for the endpoint address limits the ability of the compiler to validate the unsigned 16-bit port address.

`70040` by my early morning calculation is `10001000110011000` which is 17-bits. Ports must be 16-bits so one of these bits will be getting dropped, probably the most significant one (1).

Dropping that, yields `1000110011000` which corresponds to `4504` and it's likely the actual port that's being used.

You could try running the server on `70040` and connect to it from the the client using `4504`.